# Save classifier for future prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle, sentiment-analysis

I am new to machine learning with python and I am trying to build a Sentiment Analyzer in which I am using this [dataset](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/) and this [tutorial](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/01/19/sentiment-analysis-with-python-and-scikit-learn/). Everything is working fine on the test data. But I'm trying to save my classifier for future use. I'm doing this using pickle by saving it as

```
sentiment_analyzer = open("Sentiment_Analyzer.pkl", "wb")
pkl.dump(classifier_linear, sentiment_analyzer)
sentiment_analyzer.close()
```

Later, I'm extracting my saved analyzer by doing this

```
model_pkl = open("Sentiment_Analyzer.pkl", "rb")
model = pkl.load(model_pkl)
```

But I'm unable to understand how to call the `predict` method on my extracted `model` classifier.

Comment: `y = model.predict(X)`

Comment: I've tried it but it is showing an error `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: your input data set `X` must be in the same format as it was used for training the model...

Comment: While training, I vectorized the input list using `TfidfVectorizer` . But I don't know how to verctorize the input data set `X` .

Comment: you have to "prepare" your input data set that you are going to use for prediction in exactly the same way you've prepared the `X_train` data set...

Comment: When I'm trying to transform the input data set, it is showing `sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the `vectorizer` too, just the same way you are pickling the model. Then during future use, load both the vectorizer and classifier, transform the new X using the loaded vectorizer and then call `predict()` on classifier.